# Programmatically set RCTDevSettings.isDebuggingRemotely to false

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The `Debug JS Remotely` option is currently set to `true` in my development build. I'd like to disable this feature, but my emulator is simply to slow to do so.

Does anybody know how to disable `Debug JS Remotely` without tapping the button inside the react-native menu onShake? Perhaps, by hard-coding a value inside my apps `iOS` directory, or passing in a flag to `react-native run-ios`?

[Here's a link to every known instance of the `isDebuggingRemotely](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?q=isDebuggingRemotely&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) boolean flag I'm aiming to set to false inside the react-native GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This code may work:

iOS

```
#import <React/RCTDevSettings.h>

rootView.bridge.devSettings.isDebuggingRemotely = NO;
```

Android

```
getReactNativeHost()
    .getReactInstanceManager()
    .getDevSupportManager()
    .getDevSettings()
    .setRemoteJSDebugEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Native 0.71 you could do `NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true);`
eg: https://github.com/gusgard/react-native-devsettings/blob/master/index.ts